# SSAS - Communication link failure : Shared Memory Provider Timeout when trying to process a Big Dimension

Tags: sql, ssis, ssas, data-warehouse, olap

The processing of one dimension in the SSAS environment or in SSIS failed with the following error :

*Communication link failure; 08S01; Shared Memory Provider: Timeout error [258]. ; 08S01.*

or
*Operation canceled; HY008.*

I use the following Processing Options:

- -Parallel (All objects will be processed in a single transaction)
- -Maximum parallel tasks : Let the server decide
- -Storage mode of dimension: MOLAP

I know that this is a timeout message and I already searched for a resolution or an workaround and I couldn't find something useful.

Could anyone advice for an workaround?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open SQL Server Management Studio and connect Object Explorer to SSAS. Right click on the server node and choose Properties. Go to the General tab and check the "Show Advanced (All) Properties". The ExternalCommandTimeout property defaults to 3600 seconds which is 1 hour. If you think processing will complete in 10 hours then change that property to 36000 and click OK. Then try processing again.